# '0003 in a box' character. What is this?

Tags: c++, character

When I execute this code (to solve a problem - http://www.spoj.com/problems/TOANDFRO/) I get a '0003 in a box' in my output. 
The image '0003 in a box' in output in terminal is  at

[image]

What is it? Why am I getting that?

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void caesar(char a[], int n)
{
    int i,j;
    int p=0;
    cout<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)    
    {
        cout<<a[i];
        for(j=i;j<200;)         
        {   
            p = (2*n-1-2*i);
            j+=p;
            cout<<a[j];
            j+=2*n-p;
            cout<<a[j];         
        }
    }           
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    while(1)
    {
        char arr[200]={};   
        cin>>n;
        if(n==0)
            break;
        cin>>arr;
        caesar(arr,n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: This cipher is completely 100% unrelated to the caesar cipher.

Comment: I _speculate_ that you're accidentally reading one past the end of the array.  Have the function find the trailing NULL at the start, and put an `assert(j>0 && j<length);` before each `cout`.  Also, step through with a debugger.

Comment: Also the logic in this answer is quite confusing.  How did you derive that logic and how does it work?

Comment: I also note that your code will always display an odd number of letters, but most inputs should be displaying an _even_ number of letters.

Comment: I **highly recommend** you use a debugger and set a breakpoint at all locations that print.  Run your program. At each breakpoint, check the value of the item you are printing, in both decimal and hexadecimal.  Also, check the value in the array.  Chances are, you are display a character that has a non-printable value.

Comment: In your `caesar` method, you will have **undefined behavior** if `n` is less than 200.  The index `j` is allowed to be less than 200.  For example, you could have an array of 10 items, but the value of `j` could be 150, thus accessing beyond the limits of your array, which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

The character `'3'` has ASCII value 51. ASCII value `3` isn't printable, so sometimes other methods are used to show you've got a misplaced value in your string. Boxed 0003 is very likely such a method.

Comment: Why am I getting that? The output for one input is fine but fails for the other input.Why? @MSalters

Comment: Haven't run your program, but I spot that there are 2 values read from `a[]` on each iteration, so always an even number - even when `a[]` contains an odd number of characters. That must mean there's then one character printed incorrectly.